# Change class value on keypress jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-animations

I would like to be able to change the css property of a specific class when pressing a certain key. In this example i would like to change the css property `animation-play-state` from `running` to `paused` when <kbd>spacebar</kbd> is pressed. The following (unsurprisingly as im rubbish at jQuery) does not work:

```
$(document).bind("keypress", function(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 49) {
      $('.object').css('animation-play-state', 'paused')
   };
});
```

can anyone guide me down the right path? Thanks!

Comment: Is the `keypress` event being caught by the handler at all? Did you perhaps forget to place this code within a `document.ready` callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be because the spacebar returns `32`, and `e.which` is normalized in jQuery, so use that:

```
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
   if (e.which == 32) {
      $('.object').css('animation-play-state', 'paused')
   }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/MBF5A/) (inspect element, style is applied)

Comment: spot on thanks, and not sure where i got that wrong keycode from! Im going to try and add, if the class value is `running`, change it to `paused`, and vice versa, should i be posting a new question for this addition?

Answer (score 0):

The `keyCode` for the space bar is 32.